# concatenate in swift3.0: Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type '[]' and '[]?'

Tags: swift

get the error in Swift3.0:

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type '[FutureTrainee]' and '[FutureTrainee]?'

Code:

```
let newTrainees = data?["data"].arrayValue.map({ (json) in
                            return FutureTrainee(data: json)
                        })   
let trainees = self.futureTraineeCollection.futureTrainees + newTrainees
```

Comment: Learn how to post question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as the error suggests, you can't use `+` to add `[FutureTrainee]` (a.k.a `Array<FutureTrainee>`) and `[FutureTrainee]?` (a.k.a. `Optional<Array<FutureTrainee>>`.

`newTrainees` has type `[FutureTrainee]?` because you used optional chaining to subscript `data` with `"data"`. This code:

```
let newTrainees = data?["data"].arrayValue.map({ (json) in
                        return FutureTrainee(data: json)
                    })
```

is like:

```
var newTrainees: [FutureTrainee]?
if let data = data {
    newTrainees = data["data"].arrayValue.map({ (json) in
                      return FutureTrainee(data: json)
                  })
else {
    newTrainees = nil
}
```

You need to make sure you only append the `newTrainees` if it's not nil, like so:

```
var trainees = self.futureTraineeCollection

if let newTrainees = data?["data"].arrayValue.map{ FutureTrainee(data: $0) } {
    // If that expression is not nil, the result is bound to "newTrainees"
    trainees += newTrainees
}
```